# Geometry nodes: Get the reverse direction of a sun light

Tags: geometry-nodes

I need help from someone smarter than me here.

Using GeoNodes, I want to cast a ray from the camera position towards the sun. This is to check if the sun is occluded from the camera perspective.
This should be easy, but I can't work out how to convert the Euler rotation of my sun light to the right vector to cast a ray in.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rotate a vector[0,0,1] by the Rotation.

( If you are using a version of blender that the object info node have an **vector socket**, then use the **'Vector Rotate'** node set to *Euler*.

If you are using a version of blender that the object info node have an **rotate socket**, then use the **'Rotate Vector'** node. )